# JS/AJAX: Submitting form without button click/page refresh issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to submit video url and return an embedded code without page refresh or button. I have js function that will grab  the value of the input box. The problem is that, the function will not submit the form that will echo the embedded code. How can i make the form submit without a button click or refresh so it can echo the php code?

[EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/youtube_video/)

**JS for submitting without refresh:**

```
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                                    var timer;
                                        $('#video-input1').on('keyup', function() {
                                            var value = this.value;

                                            clearTimeout(timer);

                                            timer = setTimeout(function() {

                                                //do your submit here
                                                $("#ytVideo").submit()

                                                alert('submitted:' + value);
                                            }, 2000);
                                        });


                 //submit definition. What you want to do once submit is executed
                  $('#ytVideo').submit(function(e){
                       e.preventDefault(); //prevent page refresh
                       var form = $('#ytVideo').serialize();
                       //submit.php is the page where you submit your form
                       $.post('index.php', form, function(data){ 


                       });
                  });

            });
            </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <form  method="post" id="ytVideo" action="">
    Youtube URL:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="video-input1" type="text" value="<?php $url ?>" name="yurl">   
    </form>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
  <?php

    if($_POST)
    {
        $url     = $_POST['yurl'];


        function getYoutubeVideoID($url) {
            $formatted_url = preg_replace('~https?://(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)?(?:youtu\.be/| youtube\.com\S*[^\w\-\s])([\w\-]{11})      
                    (?=[^\w\-]|$)(?![?=&+%\w]*(?:[\'"][^<>]*>| </a>))[?=&+%\w-]*~ix','http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1',$url);
            return $formatted_url;
        }
        $formatted_url = getYoutubeVideoID($url);
        $parsed_url = parse_url($formatted_url);




        parse_str($parsed_url['query'], $parsed_query_string);
        $v = $parsed_query_string['v'];

        $hth        = 300; //$_POST['yheight'];
        $wdth       = 500; //$_POST['ywidth'];


//Iframe code

echo htmlentities ('<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$v.'" frameborder="0" width="'.$wdth.'" height="'.$hth.'"></iframe>');

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `return false` at the end of your .submit() handler:

```
$('#ytVideo').submit(function(e){
   ...
   $.post(..., function() {

   });

   return false; // add this
});
```

Comment: I have added the `return false;` to the end of the of the submit handler but nothing gets actually submitted\php echoed out. you can check the update to the link [SITE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/youtube_video/)

Comment: unable to connect to the url you've given!

Comment: can you check via firebug or chrome console to see if your post request is being sent? If so, it is an issue in your PHP script.

Comment: Yes, you are right the function is performing is task. IT must be a problem with the php